# How can I set the state in a widget that has been mounted in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, setstate

I' m new in Flutter. I made an app that has a catalogue with categories, subcategories and items (as you can see in photo). My widget tree is:

```
Catalogue(cart):{[Category-List, Subcategory-List, Item-List:{ItemRow(ListTile)}]}.
```

I'm facing the following problem: I have items in my cart and their quantity is shown on the catalogue (item rows). When I delete an item from the cart, or clear all items, I can't set the controller of the text field of the item Row to zero cause that widget (current item row) has been mounted. I use Scoped model to add, delete or update items in the cart. So, my problem is just visual. When I click on another category and then go to the previous, the controller has been set to zero correctly (cause the item rows recreated again with initstate()).

Is there any solution to my problem? Thanks!

App Image:
[image: as shown here]

Catalogue.dart Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter_slidable/flutter_slidable.dart';

import '../widgets/categories/categories_manager.dart';
import '../widgets/subcats/subcat_manager.dart';
import '../widgets/items/items_list.dart';
import '../scoped-models/main.dart';
import '../models/item.dart';

class CataloguePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String _langSelected;
  CataloguePage(this._langSelected, this.model);
  final MainModel model;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _CataloguePageState();
  }
}

class _CataloguePageState extends State<CataloguePage> {
  Widget currentPage;
  SubcatManager subcatPage;
  bool _loadingProgress;
  List<Item> _listCart;
  final SlidableController slidableController = SlidableController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    _listCart = widget.model.itemsInCart;

    _loadingProgress = true;
    widget.model
        .fetchCategories(widget.model.serverAddress, widget.model.serverPort)
        .then((bool success) {
      if (success) {
        setState(() {
          widget.model
              .fetchSubcats(widget.model.serverAddress, widget.model.serverPort,
                  widget.model.categories[0].catid)
              .then((bool success2) {
            if (success2) {
              setState(() {
                widget.model
                    .fetchItems(
                        widget.model.serverAddress,
                        widget.model.serverPort,
                        widget.model.categories[0].catid,
                        widget.model.subcats[0].subcatid)
                    .then((bool success3) {
                  if (success3) {
                    _loadingProgress = false;
                  }
                });
              });
            }
          });
        });
      } else {
        showDialog(
            barrierDismissible: true,
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return AlertDialog(
                title: Text('An error has occured.'),
                content: Text('Connection with Server failed!'),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.popUntil(
                          context, (_) => !Navigator.canPop(context));
                      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/');
                    },
                    child: Text('OK'),
                  )
                ],
              );
            });
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        title: Text('Catalogue'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.shopping_cart,
                  size: 30.0,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  showModalBottomSheet(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (BuildContext contex) {
                      return _buildCartList(_listCart);
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
              widget.model.itemsInCart.length > 0
                  ? CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 10.0,
                      child: Text(widget.model.itemsInCart.length.toString()),
                    )
                  : Container()
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: _buildBody(),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBody() {
    if (_loadingProgress) {
      return Container(
        color: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
        child: Center(
          child: Theme.of(context).platform == TargetPlatform.iOS
              ? CupertinoActivityIndicator(
                  radius: 20.0,
                )
              : CircularProgressIndicator(
                  strokeWidth: 3.0,
                ),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        color: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Flexible(
              flex: 3,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Flexible(
                    child: CategoriesManager(widget.model),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            widget.model.subcats[0].subcatid == 0
                ? Container()
                : VerticalDivider(
                    color: widget.model.themeBrightness == 1
                        ? Colors.white
                        : Colors.black,
                  ),
            widget.model.subcats[0].subcatid == 0
                ? Container()
                : Flexible(
                    flex: 3,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Flexible(
                          child: SubcatManager(widget.model),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
            VerticalDivider(
              color: widget.model.themeBrightness == 1
                  ? Colors.white
                  : Colors.black,
            ),
            Flexible(
              flex: 4,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Text('Items'),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20.0,
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                    child: ItemList(widget.model),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  Widget _buildCartList(List<Item> listCart) {
    Widget itemCartCards;
    if (listCart.length > 0) {
      itemCartCards = Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('Selected Items'),
                Text('Total Quantity: ' +
                    widget.model.cartTotalItems.toString()),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10.0,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.separated(
                separatorBuilder: (contex, index) => Divider(
                      color: widget.model.themeBrightness == 1
                          ? Colors.white
                          : Colors.black,
                    ),
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                  return Slidable(
                    key: Key(listCart[index].itemid),
                    controller: slidableController,
                    delegate: SlidableDrawerDelegate(),
                    actionExtentRatio: 0.25,
                    secondaryActions: <Widget>[
                      IconSlideAction(
                        icon: Icons.delete,
                        caption: 'Delete',
                        color: Colors.red,
                        onTap: () {
                          widget.model
                              .deleteItemFromCart(listCart[index].itemid);
                        },
                      )
                    ],
                    child: ListTile(
                      title: Text(
                        listCart[index].itemperi,
                      ),
                      trailing: Row(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          widget.model.showListItemsPrices
                              ? Text(listCart[index].itemCount.toString() +
                                  ' x ' +
                                  listCart[index].itemprice.toString() +
                                  ' €')
                              : Text(listCart[index].itemCount.toString()),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
                itemCount: listCart.length,
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                RaisedButton(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                  child: Text('Clear Order'),
                  color: Colors.red,
                  onPressed: () {
                    return showDialog<void>(
                      context: context,
                      barrierDismissible: false,
                      builder: (BuildContext context) {
                        return AlertDialog(
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                          ),
                          title: Text('Warning!'),
                          content:
                              Text('Are you sure you want to empty your cart?'),
                          actions: <Widget>[
                            FlatButton(
                                child: Text('Yes'),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                  widget.model.deleteAllCartItems();
                                }),
                            FlatButton(
                              child: Text('No'),
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                              },
                            ),
                          ],
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  },
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 20.0,
                ),
                RaisedButton(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                  child: Text('Confirm Order'),
                  color: Colors.green,
                  onPressed: () {
                    _buildJsonOrder();
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    } else {
      itemCartCards = Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Text('Your cart is empty.'),
        ),
      );
    }
    return itemCartCards;
  }

  void _buildJsonOrder() {
    final List<dynamic> _listItems = [];
    for (Item item in widget.model.itemsInCart) {
      final Map<String, dynamic> itemData = {
        'hallid': [widget.model.hallNumber],
        'tableid': [widget.model.tableNumber],
        'itemid': ['${item.itemid}'],
        'itemperi': ['${item.itemperi}'],
        'kind': [0],
        'catid': [item.itemCatId],
        'subcatid': [item.itemSubcatId],
        'quantity': [item.itemCount],
        'price': [item.itemprice]
      };
      _listItems.add(itemData);
    }

    final Map<String, dynamic> orderData = {
      'hallid': [widget.model.hallNumber],
      'tableid': [widget.model.tableNumber],
      'typeofpos': ['4'],
      'posid': [600],
      'userid': [widget.model.currentUserId],
      'items': _listItems
    };

    widget.model
        .sendOrder(
            widget.model.serverAddress, widget.model.serverPort, orderData)
        .then((bool success) {
      if (success) {
        showDialog(
            barrierDismissible: false,
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return AlertDialog(
                title: Text('Success.'),
                content: Text('Your order has been placed successfully!'),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      widget.model.deleteAllCartItems();
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                    child: Text('OK'),
                  )
                ],
              );
            });
      } else {
        showDialog(
            barrierDismissible: false,
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return AlertDialog(
                title: Text('An error has occured.'),
                content: Text('Something went wrong with your order.'),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                    child: Text('OK'),
                  )
                ],
              );
            });
      }
    });
  }
}
```

ItemList.dart Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:scoped_model/scoped_model.dart';

import '../../models/item.dart';
import '../../scoped-models/main.dart';
import './item_row.dart';

class ItemList extends StatefulWidget {
  final MainModel model;
  ItemList(this.model);
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _ItemListState();
  }
}

class _ItemListState extends State<ItemList> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  Widget _buildItemList(List<Item> items) {
    Widget itemCards;
    if (items.length > 0) {
      itemCards = ListView.separated(
        separatorBuilder: (contex, index) => Divider(
              color: widget.model.themeBrightness == 1
                  ? Colors.white
                  : Colors.black,
            ),
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
          return ItemRow(widget.model, items[index]);
        },
        itemCount: items.length,
      );
    } else {
      itemCards = Container();
    }
    return itemCards;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: ScopedModelDescendant<MainModel>(
            builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child, MainModel model) {
              return _buildItemList(model.items);
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

ItemRow.dart Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:scoped_model/scoped_model.dart';

import '../../models/item.dart';
import '../../scoped-models/main.dart';

class ItemRow extends StatefulWidget {
  final MainModel model;
  final Item item;
  ItemRow(this.model, this.item);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _ItemRowState();
  }
}

class _ItemRowState extends State<ItemRow> {
  int _itemCount;
  TextEditingController _itemCountController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    setState(() {
      _itemCount = widget.item.itemCount;
      _itemCountController = TextEditingController(text: _itemCount.toString());
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(ItemRow oldWidget) {
    if (oldWidget.item.itemid != widget.item.itemid) {
      setState(() {
        _itemCount = widget.item.itemCount;
        _itemCountController =
            TextEditingController(text: _itemCount.toString());
      });
    }
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScopedModelDescendant<MainModel>(
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child, MainModel model) {
        return _buildItem(widget.item);
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildItem(Item item) {
    return ListTile(
      leading: CircleAvatar(
          backgroundImage: item.itemimage == ''
              ? AssetImage('assets/noimage.png')
              : NetworkImage(item.itemimage)),
      title: Text(
        item.itemperi,
      ),
      trailing: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: <Widget>[
          widget.model.showListItemsPrices
              ? Text(
                  item.itemprice.toString() + ' €',
                )
              : Container(),
          widget.model.showListItemsCart ? VerticalDivider() : Container(),
          widget.model.showListItemsCart
              ? _buildListItemCart(item)
              : Container()
        ],
      ),
      onTap: () {
        if (widget.model.clickItems) {
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/item/' + item.itemid);
        }
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildListItemCart(Item item) {
    return Container(
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          GestureDetector(
            onLongPress: () {
              if (_itemCount != 0) {
                setState(() {
                  _itemCount = 0;
                  _itemCountController =
                      TextEditingController(text: _itemCount.toString());
                  widget.model.deleteItemFromCart(item.itemid);
                });
              }
            },
            child: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.remove),
              onPressed: () {
                if (_itemCount != 0) {
                  setState(() {
                    _itemCount--;
                    _itemCountController =
                        TextEditingController(text: _itemCount.toString());
                    if (_itemCount == 0) {
                      widget.model.deleteItemFromCart(item.itemid);
                    } else {
                      widget.model.updateItemCart(item.itemid, _itemCount);
                    }
                  });
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            width: 30.0,
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(border: InputBorder.none),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              controller: _itemCountController,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(),
              onTap: () {
                _itemCountController.selection = TextSelection(
                    baseOffset: 0,
                    extentOffset: _itemCountController.text.length);
              },
              onSubmitted: (value) {
                if (value == 0.toString()) {
                  widget.model.deleteItemFromCart(item.itemid);
                }
                if (value != 0.toString() && _itemCount == 0) {
                  widget.model.addItemToCart(
                      item.itemid,
                      item.itemperi,
                      item.itemprice,
                      int.parse(value),
                      int.parse(widget.model.selectedCatid),
                      int.parse(widget.model.selectedSubcatId));
                }
                if (value != 0.toString() && _itemCount != 0) {
                  widget.model.updateItemCart(item.itemid, int.parse(value));
                }
                _itemCount = int.parse(value);
                TextEditingController(text: _itemCount.toString());
              },
            ),
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(
                () {
                  _itemCount++;
                  _itemCountController =
                      TextEditingController(text: _itemCount.toString());
                  if (_itemCount == 1) {
                    widget.model.addItemToCart(
                        item.itemid,
                        item.itemperi,
                        item.itemprice,
                        _itemCount,
                        int.parse(widget.model.selectedCatid),
                        int.parse(widget.model.selectedSubcatId));
                  } else {
                    widget.model.updateItemCart(item.itemid, _itemCount);
                  }
                },
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

ScopedModelItems.dart Code:

```
import 'package:scoped_model/scoped_model.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

import '../models/item.dart';
import '../scoped-models/main.dart';

mixin ItemsModel on Model {
  MainModel model;
  List<Item> _items = [];
  List<Item> itemsEmpty = [];
  int _cartTotalItems = 0;
  List<Item> _itemsCartEmpty = [];
  Item _itemDetails;

  Item get itemDetails {
    return _itemDetails;
  }

  List<Item> get items {
    return List.of(_items);
  }

  List<Item> get itemsInCart {
    return _itemsCartEmpty;
  }

  int get cartTotalItems {
    if (_cartTotalItems == null) {
      _cartTotalItems = 0;
    }
    return _cartTotalItems;
  }

  void initState() {
    _items.forEach(_addItem);
  }

  void _addItem(Item item) {
    itemsEmpty.add(item);
  }

  void addItemToCart(String itemid, String itemperi, num itemprice,
      int itemQuantity, int itemCatid, int itemSubcatid) {
    Item item = Item(
        itemid: itemid,
        itemperi: itemperi,
        itemprice: itemprice,
        itemCount: itemQuantity,
        itemCatId: itemCatid,
        itemSubcatId: itemSubcatid);
    _itemsCartEmpty.add(item);
    _cartTotalItems += itemQuantity;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void updateItemCart(String itemid, int itemQuantity) {
    _itemsCartEmpty.forEach((item) {
      if (item.itemid == itemid) {
        _cartTotalItems -= item.itemCount;
        item.itemCount = itemQuantity;
        _cartTotalItems += itemQuantity;
      }
    });
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void deleteItemFromCart(String itemid) {
    _itemsCartEmpty.forEach((item) {
      if (item.itemid == itemid) {
        _cartTotalItems -= item.itemCount;
      }
    });
    _itemsCartEmpty.removeWhere((item) => item.itemid == itemid);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void deleteAllCartItems() {
    _itemsCartEmpty.removeRange(0, _itemsCartEmpty.length);
    _cartTotalItems = 0;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<bool> fetchItems(String serverAddress, String serverPort,
      dynamic catid, dynamic subcatid) {
    return http.get(
        'http://$serverAddress:$serverPort/cats/$catid/subcats/$subcatid/items/GR',
        headers: {'Accept': 'application/json'}).then((http.Response response) {
      if (response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 201) {
        final List<Item> fetchedItemList = [];
        final List<dynamic> itemListData = json.decode(response.body);
        itemListData.forEach((dynamic itemData) {
          String imageData = '', periData = '';
          if (itemData['item_image_path'] != '') {
            imageData = 'http://$serverAddress:$serverPort/photos/' +
                itemData['item_image_path'];
          }
          if (itemData['item_webperi'] == '') {
            periData = itemData['item_peri'];
          } else {
            periData = itemData['item_webperi'];
          }
          final Item item = Item(
              itemid: itemData['item_id'],
              itemperi: periData,
              itemimage: imageData,
              itemprice: itemData['item_price'],
              itemCount: 0);
          if (_itemsCartEmpty.isNotEmpty) {
            for (Item itemCart in _itemsCartEmpty) {
              if (itemCart.itemid == item.itemid) {
                item.itemCount = itemCart.itemCount;
              }
            }
          }
          fetchedItemList.add(item);
        });
        _items = fetchedItemList;
        notifyListeners();
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }).catchError((error) {
      print(error);
      notifyListeners();
      return false;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there's no code I'll just list the common errors that cause this when using scoped model:

**1. Not calling notify**

You have to call notifyListeners() in your scoped model to update the UI that's using your porperties.

**2. Not telling model to rebuild**

If you're not using a ScopedModelDescendent widget and instead you're getting your model using

```
appModel = ScopedModel.of<AppModel>(context);
```

change your code to

```
appModel = ScopedModel.of<AppModel>(context, rebuildOnChange: true);
```

If you're doing both of these then please post your code for your UI and scoped model so that it's easier to offer our help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I embedded the code in my original post. I m calling notifyListeners as you can see and I use ScopedModelDescendent in ItemList.dart file.

Comment: @panos There's a lot of things wrong there in your code. I don't think one thing will solve it. Your scoped model is supposed to manage your state, you shouldn't store it in your main model. You should use the code I showed above ScopedModel.of to get your model in your child widgets. Then you also need to move the model setting out of setState. Your scoped model will manage all of your state.

Comment: @panos Move your models out of your UI state files and into your scoped model. I have an example of how the architecture should look when using scoped model [here](https://github.com/FilledStacks/flutter-architecture-skeletons).

Comment: @panos You're managing state or maintaining reference to it in more than 2 ways so it's very hard to tell where the problem is, and also will be hard for you to maintain.

Comment: I found a solution! I m holding the item id that is deleted in a variable into my scoped model. Then, in the itemRow (in didUpdateWidget()), checking if row's itemid is equal with the deleted id. If it does, I m setting the controller to zero, or else I m just leaving it as it was before. Thank you again for the answer. I' ll check your document for extra help in the future :) .